# How do I get the AJAX top menu that StackOverflow has?

Tags: javascript, ajax

You know, the menu that pops up when you get to the site and you can click the 'x' to the right to remove it. What technology is this (I assume AJAX) and what terms do I need to search for to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [code](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/07/top-floating-message-box-using-jquery.html) to do it with JQuery.

Html:

```
<div id="message_box">
    <img id="close_message" style="float:right;cursor:pointer" src="12-em-cross.png" />
    The floating message goes here
</div>

<div>
  ..............
  other content goes here
  ..................
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#message_box {
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
z-index: 10;
background:#ffc;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
width:99%;
}
```

JQuery (javascript):

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
  $('#message_box').animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 350});
});

//when the close button at right corner of the message box is clicked
$('#close_message').click(function()
{
  //the messagebox gets scrool down with top property and gets hidden with zero opacity
  $('#message_box').animate({ top:"+=15px",opacity:0 }, "slow");
});
```

You can see a [Live Demo here](http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/floating-message-jquery/).

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly thank you Daok! However since I have it in my header.php file once the user clicks it away it is gone, however when they view another page in the site it comes back. Any ideas on the proper way to remove this?

Comment: You need to make an Ajax call in the click function that will call a page on your server that will save somewhere(database,xml, file or cookie) that the user have closed the top menu. When you generate the header.php, you will need to check where you saved the state of the click and if an entry is wrote than you do not generate the code to display the top menu.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

As a side note, that box is actually static if you don't have scripts enabled, so it is not AJAX, just DOM scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was implemented via jQuery, but I'm not sure which plugin they used or how it's configured.

Comment: do you know the technique or definition so I can google some tutorials? 'Sliding menu' isn't it.