# Are there any AJAX NON-MODEL message box in ASP.NET Web Control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-controls

I am looking for some popup message / reminder like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427732/how-do-i-get-the-ajax-top-menu-that-stackoverflow-has) and [that](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html), in a ready to use control in ASP.NET.

PS. For some reasons, I am forced NOT TO WRITE ANY JAVASCRIPT. I can use only Web Controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [AlwaysVisible control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AlwaysVisibleControl/AlwaysVisibleControl.aspx) in the AJAX Toolkit? That's the closest to the SO notification bar that sits at the top that I'm aware of, although there are undoubtedly others.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But it does not ship with a property for the control button to close, like the CancelControlID in ModalPopup.

If I use it, I will have to make a button and call AJAX postback with a UpdatePanel. Is just too slow and heavy.

I know, a onClick JavaScript does the closing tricks, but it is forbidden.